# i am getting this error in tableau public whenever i upload my dashboard?

Tags: tableau-api, public

Why am I getting "Warning: This viz contains at least one component that renders content from outside Tableau Public. Be careful when providing credentials or other sensitive information."?
after this the link wont work .tabl
[image]